# Add image to view (background)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have added an image to my viewcontroller in code. Without the use of an imageview. This is how i did it:

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,100,500)];
backgroundImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage"];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
```

There are 2 things i need a litte help with. How can i get the image to the back of the view, behind the labels, buttons etc.
And how do i get the image to fit all iphone screen sizes?
I hope you can help me.
Much thanks

Comment: `[self.view insertSubview:backgroundImage atIndex:0];`?

Comment: Try using insertSubview: backgroundImage atIndex:0 to put the image behind all the other views.

Comment: Simply use `colorWithPatternImage` property to set color
 
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage"]];

Comment: @guardabrazo it worked. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked two questions-

**Question 1** : *How to get the labels/ buttons other subviews visible over the image?*

**Answer** -

Just add image before any other subview.

And there are two ways to set a background image to a `UIView` –

You can set your `view` background color to color created with `UIColor’s` `colorWithPaternImage`.
You can add a `UIImageView` `subview` to your `view`.

`colorWithPaternImage` was created to use small images to create a pattern image that will be repeated. Using it with large images wont be a wise decision. So if you want to have a patterned image background with uses small images which will be repeated to fill the background, then you should use `colorWithPaternImage`, as it will do it quickly and wont consume much memory.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
```

If you have a full size background image, then you should definitely use the `UIImageView`. Using `UIImageView` will save a lot of memory in this case.

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
```

**Question 2** : *How to show the image as per the device/ screen resolution?*

**Answer** -

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Use the above `screenBounds` to set the frame of `ImageView`.

Comment: Good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage"]];

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code with this :

```
    UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage"];
    [self.view insertView:backgroundImage atIndex:0];
```

Hope this helps. Let me know it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply get screen size of device by following method to make it compatible to all device.

```
CGRect rect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
```

create UIImageView object of that frame size and insert at index 0 of UIView.

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage =[[UIImageView alloc]  initWithFrame:rect];  // This will set image fit to all iphone...

backgroundImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image.png"];
[self.view insertSubview:backgroundImage atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage =[[UIImageView alloc]  initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];  // This will set image fit to all iphone...

backgroundImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image.png"];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
```

// This line will send image behind all the other controls

```
[backgroundImage sendSubviewToBack:self.view];
```